# How to write Postgre SQL query havjng AS for changing column name in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

I am trying to get values of a column(CATALOG_NBR) in CodeIgniter but somehow i think it do not take column names with underscore. Now i want to rename the column name by using AS. I search for it in the documentation but did not find the answer.

**My Query:**

```
/* $code is parameter that i am taking from URL (combination of values from SUBJECT and CATALOG_NBR column) */ 

$param = str_split($code, 4);
$row = $this->db->get_where('PS_CU_CRSE_CTLG_VW', array('SUBJECT' => $param[0], 'CATALOG_NBR'   => $param[1]))->row_array();
```

In where clause inside array i am using CATALOG_NBR which is not working fine. I want to rename it somehow as i have tried running the query in Postgre and it works when you rename the column.

Thanks !!!

Comment: **print** the last query `$this->db->last_query()` and check if its correct. if it is `var_dump($row)` should give desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify an alias in the select clause, like this:

```
$this->db->select('column AS alias')->from('table')->where('column', $condition)->get()->result();
```

Comment: But it will not return all the columns but only that specific column as you are selection only one column.

I want query like this..

SELECT * FROM table_name where column1(to be renamed) = result1 AND column2 = result2

Comment: It was just an example, you can replace it with '*' or add more columns like 'column1, column2' or even skip the select i think and it will take all. Maybe i misunderstood the question, so you want an alias in where clause? I don't think you can do that, you can only use them in GROUP BY, ORDER BY or HAVING clause. Maybe i am wrong.